# Why does my program just stop in Python with no error?

Tags: python

Compiler just stops
[image]

```
import time
import random

def game():
    score1=0
    score2=0
    name1=input("Player 1, please enter your name: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    name2=input("Player 2, please enter your name: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(name1, "rolls two dice")
    dice1=random.randint(0,6)
    dice2=random.randint(0,6)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if dice1 == dice2:
        print(name1, "rolled a double! They may roll a third dice, whatever number they roll will be the number of points they earn.")
        dice3=random.randint(0,6)
        score1=score1+dice3
        print(name1, "rolled", dice3)
    else:
        total=dice1+dice2
        if (total % 2) == 0:
            score1=score1+10
        else:
            score1=score1-5

#Start
goes=0
while goes >10:
    goes=0+1
    game()
```

When I run my code it works until it rolls two dice, which is when it just stops, the compiler returns to its opening state. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong either, help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: goes will never equal 10, not entirely sure what the issue is you're trying to solve though

Comment: you have  problem is here `goes=0+1` you keep restarting

Comment: unfinished yet, sorry i should have clarified.

Comment: each iteration players are asked for names. Maybe make getting names a seperate function and call it only once? Then roll as many dice as you want with `goes+=1`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you have to fix here.

1. `while goes > 10`
   This should be `while goes < 10`. `goes` is initially `0`, and your condition checks for goes greater than 10, which will never work and wont enter while loop.
2. `goes=0+1` This should be `goes = goes + 1` or `goes += 1`. You code will set `goes` to `1` every time it enters while loop.